# oracle sql how to select first row and last row two select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two selects. First one is

```
select usuario,fecha from (
select mam.fecha fecha , u.COD_USUARIO usuario
from r_mod_asignar_material mam ,
r_usuarios u
where  mam.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario
and u.ID_CENTRO_GESTION = '1'
and trunc(mam.FECHA) = to_date('13/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')
and mam.ACCION = 'A'

order by mam.fecha asc ) 
where rownum = 1) a
```

This select returns fecha and usuario.

Now I have another select, it is the same but changing the where.

```
select usuario,fecha from (
select mam.fecha fecha , u.COD_USUARIO usuario
from r_mod_asignar_material mam ,
r_usuarios u
where  mam.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario
and u.ID_CENTRO_GESTION = '1'
and trunc(mam.FECHA) = to_date('13/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')
and mam.ACCION = 'A'

order by mam.fecha desc ) b1
where rownum = 1

) b
```

I want to return fecha and usuario from first and second select where usuario is the same.

I try inline select, but the usuario returned by the first select is not the same returned by the second select

```
select a.fecha fecha1, a.usuario usuario1 ,b.fecha fecha2,b.usuario usuario2
from (
select usuario,fecha from (
select mam.fecha fecha , u.COD_USUARIO usuario
from r_mod_asignar_material mam ,
r_usuarios u
where  mam.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario
and u.ID_CENTRO_GESTION = '1'
and trunc(mam.FECHA) = to_date('13/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')
and mam.ACCION = 'A'

order by mam.fecha asc ) 
where rownum = 1) a
join
(select usuario,fecha from (
select mam.fecha fecha , u.COD_USUARIO usuario
from r_mod_asignar_material mam ,
r_usuarios u
where  mam.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario
and u.ID_CENTRO_GESTION = '1'
and trunc(mam.FECHA) = to_date('13/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')
and mam.ACCION = 'A'

order by mam.fecha desc ) b1
where rownum = 1

) b
on a.usuario = b.usuario
```

Comment: one of the SQL statement has `order by mam.fecha desc` while the other has `order by mam.fecha asc`

Comment: sample data would really help here, plus, the expected result as well

Comment: `union all` them together.

Comment: On a sidenote: 1. We don't use comma separated joins anymore. They were made redundant in SQL92, where 92 stands for 1992! Oracle adapted the new join syntax in Oracle 9i. 2. For date constants in queries we'd use date literals: `trunc(mam.fecha) = date '2018-09-13'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use row_number() instead perhaps:

```
SELECT
    usuario
  , fecha
FROM (
    SELECT
        mam.fecha                                                              fecha
      , u.COD_USUARIO                                                          usuario
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.cod_usuario ORDER BY mam.fecha ASC)  AS rn_asc
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.cod_usuario ORDER BY mam.fecha DESC) AS rn_desc
    FROM r_mod_asignar_material mam
    INNER JOIN r_usuarios u ON mam.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario
    WHERE u.ID_CENTRO_GESTION = '1'
    AND trunc(mam.FECHA) = to_date('13/09/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
    AND mam.ACCION = 'A'
    ) b1
WHERE (rn_asc = 1 OR rn_desc = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle's `KEEP FIRST/LAST`:

```
select
  min(mam.fecha) as primera_hora,
  min(u.cod_usuario) keep (dense_rank first mam.fecha) as primero_usuario,
  max(mam.fecha) as ultima_hora,
  max(u.cod_usuario) keep (dense_rank last mam.fecha) as ultimo_usuario
from r_mod_asignar_material mam
join r_usuarios u on u.cod_usuario = mam.cod_usuario and u.id_centro_gestion = 1
where trunc(mam.fecha) = date '2018-09-13'
and mam.accion = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

use union all between them ,this will work:

```
select usuario,fecha from (
select mam.fecha fecha , u.COD_USUARIO usuario
from r_mod_asignar_material mam ,
r_usuarios u
where  mam.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario
and u.ID_CENTRO_GESTION = '1'
and trunc(mam.FECHA) = to_date('13/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')
and mam.ACCION = 'A'
order by mam.fecha asc ) 
where rownum = 1) a
union all
select usuario,fecha from (
select mam.fecha fecha , u.COD_USUARIO usuario
from r_mod_asignar_material mam ,
r_usuarios u
where  mam.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario
and u.ID_CENTRO_GESTION = '1'
and trunc(mam.FECHA) = to_date('13/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')
and mam.ACCION = 'A'

order by mam.fecha desc ) b1
where rownum = 1;
```